# What is the problem with this array of ints?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm declaring an array of ints in the following way:

```
input = sc1.nextInt();
static int array [];
```

When I try to feed the array with a for loop, appears next message java.lang.NullPointerException.

This is the code:

```
for (int j=2; j<=input; j++){
    if (input%j==0) {
        array[counter1]=j;
        counter1++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize it. `int[] array = new int[input];`

Comment: Re, "I'm declaring... This is the code:..." Those variable declarations _are_ code. And the declaration of the class is code, and the declaration of the method that contains the `for` loop is code. The more you show the better. In fact, for such a simple example as this, you probably should just include the entire program, as well as the entire text of the error message.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know for sure because you left out so much of your program, but @unmitigated probably is correct: The exception probably was thrown from this line, `array[counter1]=j;` because `array` probably was `null`.

Your `array` variable is *not* an array. Java arrays and Java objects are never stored *in* variables. They can only exist on the heap, and Java variables can only hold [*references*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)) to arrays and objects. Your program must first explicitly *create* the array before it can use it.  Just like how @unmitigated showed you:

```
array = new int[input];
```

The `new` operator creates a new object or, as in this case, a new array on the heap, and it returns a reference to the new thing. Then, the assignment operator, `=`, stores the reference into your `array` variable.

---

Same goes for objects:  If your program has some `class Foobar`, and a `Foobar` variable, then it must explicitly create an instance and assign it to the variable before the variable can be used.

```
Foobar myFoo;
...
myFoo = new Foobar( /*constructor arguments, if any, go here*/ );
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other programming languages in java almost always you have to `initialize` your variable.

To initialize an array, you have to define a length for it. I don't know what are you trying to do but I'll give you an example:

```
int array[] = new int[10];
```

EDIT: I suggest you to give more attention to the @Solomon Slow answer, he explained it well!